# Communication from Docker-Container to outside

Tags: docker, networking, grafana

I am quite new to the docker topics and I have a question of connecting container services with traditional ones.

Currently I am thinking of replacing an traditional grafana installation (directly on a linux server) with a grafana docker container.

In grafana I have to connect to different data sources like a mysql instance, a Winsows SQL Database and so on. So grafana is doing a pull of data. All these data sources reside (and will still reside) on other hosts and they are not containers.

So how can I implement that my container is able to communicate with this data sources? Is it possible by default or do I have to implement a special kind of network? I saw that there is an option called macvlan...is that the correct way?

BR
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work out of the box, as far as I understand. At least, I'm using Grafana inside a docker container and it works perfectly.

You can test a connectivity from inside your docker container to some external resource by opening a container shell like this:

```
docker exec -it <container ID> /bin/bash
```

And then

```
root@a9cbebfc4564:/# curl google.com
```

Or

```
root@a9cbebfc4564:/# ping <bla-bla>
```

*Commands above depend on a docker image environment (like OS or installed software), but this can be solved in a same was as you can do on a regular Unix env*

P.S. I encountered a docker2host connection issue once, but it was due to incorrect firewall configuration on a host side.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are replacing a traditional installation, you can start with [host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). This mode give you same connectivity experience as installing on the host. A quick start is as simple as:

`docker run --network host grafana/grafana`

Notice there's no need to `--publish` or `--publish-all` ports as the Grafana container now share the host network.